# How to set up pro-guard rules for Cloud Endpoints v2 in Android project

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

What should my `proguard-rules.pro` file look like so that `minifyEnabled true` works with Cloud Endpoints v2?

When I release my app to Google Play and I have `minifyEnabled true` in my gradle, I get class not found or nulls for the Cloud Endpoints library classes.

Is there any guide or information on how to configure `proguard-rules.pro` in Android so proguard works with the Cloud Endpoints V2 libraries?

Or is there some other way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `minifyEnabled = true` along with ProGuard, you should add this in your proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keep public class com.google.cloud.** {  
    public *;  
}
```

if your dependencies for cloud endpoints start with `com.google.cloud` or

```
-keep public class com.google.endpoints.** {  
    public *;  
}
```

if your dependencies for cloud endpoints start with `com.google.endpoints` or add both (depending on the dependencies you add).